# Cambiar un texto con javascript letra a letra

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, setinterval

Quiero hacer algo parecido a esto para las alertas de streamlabs (cuando tienes un nuevo suscriptor y eso):
https://codepen.io/alticreation/pen/ZYdopE

Al principio lo que hace es que recoge un elemento del DOM y cambia la string por una string aleatoria. Eso lo hace bien. Luego, al pasar medio segundo, cambia la string aleatoria por la string final y quiero que se vaya viendo el proceso como en el ejemplo.
En la consola también se ve que el proceso lo sigue bien, pero lo hace todo de golpe.

Lo he intentado también con setInterval, pero tampoco he conseguido que funcione.

```js
window.onload
var domElement = document.getElementById("alert-message");
var texto = domElement.innerHTML;
var falso = ""
var longitud = String(texto).length;

var caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZabccdefghijklmnñopqrstuwxyz0123456789-+*/|}{[]~\\\":;?/.><=+-_)(*&^%$#@!)}";

for(var i = 0; i < longitud; i++){
 falso += caracteres.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101));
}
falso = String(falso);
domElement.innerHTML = falso
function cambiar(){
 for(i = 0; i < longitud + 1; i++){
  domElement.innerHTML = falso
  setDelay(i);
 }
};
cambiar();

function setDelay(i) {
 setTimeout(function(){
  falso = texto.substr(0,i) + falso.substr(i);
  console.log(falso);
  domElement.innerHTML = falso
 }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id= "alert-message">Pepe nos está siguiendo</div>
        <script src="src/prueba.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando la función de retorno es anónima o incluyes paréntesis, se ejecuta inmediatamente, sin espera.

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('Se ejecuta sin esperar'); }, 2000);
setTimeout(alert('Se ejecuta sin esperar'), 2000);
// Funciona sin paréntesis
setTimeout(miAlerta, 2000);
function miAlerta() {
    alert('Se ejecuta después de 2 segundos');
}
// Especifica los parámetros a la función después de la espera
setTimeout(alert, 2000, 'Se ejecuta después de 2 segundos');
```

Desconozco cómo hacerlo con función anónima, pero aquí hay una solución: Debes crear una función a ejecutar e incluirla como primer parámetro sin paréntesis, para este caso, basta con la función cambiar y llamadas recursivas hasta que se complete la cadena.

```js
window.onload
var domElement = document.getElementById("alert-message");
var texto = domElement.innerHTML;
var falso = ""
var longitud = String(texto).length;

var caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZabccdefghijklmnñopqrstuwxyz0123456789-+*/|}{[]~\\\":;?/.><=+-_)(*&^%$#@!)}";

for(var i = 0; i < longitud; i++){
 falso += caracteres.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101));
}
falso = String(falso);
domElement.innerHTML = falso
var i = 0;
function cambiar(){
    if(i <= longitud) {
     falso = texto.substr(0,i) + falso.substr(i);
    console.log(falso);
    domElement.innerHTML = falso;
      i++;
      setTimeout(cambiar, 50);
    }
};
// Esperar un segundo antes de iniciar
setTimeout(cambiar, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id= "alert-message">Pepe nos está siguiendo</div>
        <script src="src/prueba.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```